# .htaccess for public folder as root and sub folder for subdirectory

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, .htaccess

I'm currently trying to achieve this using .htaccess

```
http://example.com - using public_html folder
http://example.com/places - using the places folder
```

This is the current structure of my folders and also both public_html and places folder are a wordpress site

```
root
|-public_html
|-places
| |-.htaccess
|-.htaccess
```

**root/.htaccess**

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond ${HTTP_HOST} ^example.com$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond ${HTTP_HOST} ^www.example.com$
RewriteCond ${REQUEST_URI} !public_html/
RewriteRule (.*) /public_html/$1 [L]

# This is a must
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule ^index.php$ - [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

**root/places/.htaccess**

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /places/
    RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /places/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Comment: what is the problem you are facing ?